# Есть ли способ написать тело класса вне класса в котором он был объявлен?

Tags: c++, ооп, классы

Я новичок в программировании по C++, по этому нередко встречаюсь с определенными отличиями, как в синтаксисе, так и в реализации некоторых аспектов. Очень часто в ооп. Так вот, одна из основных идей, который я захотел реализовать в C++ вдохновившись от иного языка. Но как бы не знаю как, тут-то и нужна ваша помощь.

```
class A
{
  private:
  class B;
  
  public:
  A();

};
```

Вот в этом фрагменте кода, я объявил о создании нового приватного класса внутри другого класса. Однако мне бы хотелось его реализацию написать вне класса, или вообще в другом файле. Как можно это сделать ? Есть ли метод тоже самое сделать для шаблонных классов.

Дополнено: То что я пробывал с шаблонными классами:

```
template <typename T> class My_forwarded_list
{
public:

    My_forwarded_list();

private:
    class Node;
    int __size;
    Node* head;
};

template <typename T>
My_forwarded_list<T>::My_forwarded_list() : head{ new Node }
{
}

//Ошибка имеется вот тут, получаю следующую ошибку. E0498 template argument list must match the parameter lis

template <typename T>
My_forwarded_list<T>::Node
{

};
```

Comment: A::A() {...} - конструктор

Comment: `class A::B { ...`

Comment: Про методы знаю, именно интересует реализация класса B вне класса A, даже не смотря на то, что первый объявлен в приватной зоне класса второго.

Comment: user7860670 опыт показывает, что такой метод недействителен, по крайней мере я так пребывал для шаблонных классов.

Comment: @Vlad *"опыт показывает, что такой метод недействителен"* - такие слова следует подкреплять, приводя [mcve] В примере в вопросе шаблонные классы отсутствуют. Соответственно и в ответах их не будет.

Comment: Ключевое слово `class` пропущено

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Всё работает:

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
private:
    class B;
public:
    A();
};

class A::B {
public:
    void show() {
        std::cout << "B::show()\n";
    }
};

A::A() {
    B b;
    b.show();
}

int main() {
    A a;
}
```

> ```
> $ g++ -std=c++17 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror temp.cpp && ./a.out 
> B::show()
> ```